# Writing Android remote control Desktop

Tags: android, windows

I am thinking to try writing an app that can use android phone to remote control the desktop.

Just want to make sure my concept is correct.

1. So for the android able to
   communicate with the desktop, I will
   need some kind of protocol like...
   maybe Bluetooth? In my desktop, I
   should have a service app that open
   Bluetooth connection for my Android.
2. Is Bluetooth is a good connection
   for writing remote control?
3. Is it possible to use the Bluetooth
   receiver from mouse to do the same
   thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start with remote desktop I really recommend to you to first do a Desktop pc version before starting with the Android version.
Like [Teamviewer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEcQFjAC&url=http://www.teamviewer.com/&rct=j&q=remote%20desktop&ei=sBK7TbHHC4qKhQfluqXQBQ&usg=AFQjCNGHCZ-GmRwuRFVdksOAVFXeCWTYwg&sig2=2IooVKAgsuejICptYytE9Q&cad=rja). I recommend to do it with WiFi (WLAN) internet. Bluetooth needs a distance of maximum 20 metres. But if you want to do it fast, Bluetooth (instead of WLAN) could be better to do a presentation in the same room.

If you want to access the screen by using your phone, you need to access the mouse on desktop pc (Using of Mouse's bluetooth is not really possible). I think that is very simple. You also need to drive the keyboard. The difficult thing here is to do it with correct keyboard settings and character transmission.
[Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx)

Also one of the most important things is to get it quick: Use [Port forwarding](http://portforward.com/) on your router and on client side. That is a very tricky thing, Teamviewer is one of the best applications I've seen. They do not need it but still are working quick and direct.

Also take a look to your streamed images. Best way is to use [MPEG4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC). But could be very tricky.

I would do it in the future with my WP7 and a DotNet app. Perhaps we can work together.

Comment: ahh, I thought for steaming images I can just keep on capturing screen shoot of desktop and send it to the mobile.... maybe I should check how to use mp4... Actually I don't even have a andriod phone now, just want to get some prepration before I buy one lol

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done using Bluetooth, but a better option would be to use WiFi because it has more range and higher bandwidth. You can use sockets to communicate between mobile and desktop. Java provides a class java.awt.Robot which you can use to simulate mouse and keyboard events.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
robot.mouseMove(x,y)
```

Robot class also let's you capture screen, so it is possible for you to replicate desktop screen on mobile just like teamviewer. The complete process of creating an android based remote control is detailed [here](http://codesmith.in/control-pc-from-android-app-using-java/)